# Why do the controls with transparent style look different in the IDE and on the target device?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

I have problem a with transparent style on Android. I'm using `TStyleBook` with  "Transparent.Style" file. Project looks fine in the IDE but combo edit and edit objects are not visible on Android device. I can type in the edit, but I can't see their borders on the HTC One V device.

IDE screenshot:

[image]

HTC One V screenshot:

[image]

What might be the reason of this look ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install update pack 2. There is too many errors have been fixed.

[Release Notes for XE5 Update 2](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Release_Notes_for_XE5_Update_2)

[Fix list for Update 2 for RAD Studio XE5, Delphi XE5 and C++Builder XE5](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/43522)